# How can I make the tabbar action hidden when the view is loading?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an iphone application in which I am adding a view after calling a webservice,having a loading view inside the view.But when that view is loading somebody clicks on my tabbar item the app is crashing.I need to have that tabbar action to be hidden untill that view is loaded.I dont want to hide the tabbar,only action,Can anybody know How to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the user interaction with the tabbar like this:

```
[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

And enable it later after your webservice has finished loading or failed.

But you should stop your webservice in the

```
-(void)viewDidUnload
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a boolean to YES in webViewDidStartLoad as a semaphore, and set it to NO in webViewDidFinishLoad.  Condition your tab bar action so that it won't happen if that boolean is YES.  You can test in webViewDidStartLoad if you have other web view loads that you don't want this delay to occur during.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loading view(HUD) that covers the hole window, so the user can't touch anything while the networking operation is working.

SVProgressHud is a good one.