# IOS 5 MBProgressHUD disable tab bar buttons while loading data. (userInteractionEnabled = NO)

Tags: ios5, tabbarcontroller, mbprogresshud

I use `MBProgressHUD` when loading data and user can press the another tab button during the process. `MBProgressHUD` only disable the view contents.
I checked other posts but didn't see anything helps me to disable the tab button.

I tried to set `tabbaritem.userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` but I couldn't find a way to access that. I can do it in storyboard but can't switch it back to `YES`.

My question is; from my viewController is there any way to access `tabbarcontroller.tabbaritem.userInteractionEnabled` ?

Comment: For people looking for similar question; Use tabbar delegate       -(BOOL) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController  return NO when App is busy.

Answer (score 1):

I use category:

UIViewController+MBProgressHUD.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class MBProgressHUD;

@interface UIViewController (MBProgressHUD)

- (MBProgressHUD *)showHUD;
- (MBProgressHUD *)showHUDFromTitle:(NSString *)title;
- (MBProgressHUD *)showHUDFromTitle:(NSString *)title completedImage:(BOOL)completedImage;
- (void)hideHUD;

@end
```

And UIViewController+MBProgressHUD.m

```
#import "UIViewController+MBProgressHUD.h"
#import <MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.h>

@implementation UIViewController (MBProgressHUD)

- (MBProgressHUD *)showHUDFromTitle:(NSString *)title {
    UIView *view;
    if (self.tabBarController.view != nil) {
        view = self.tabBarController.view;
    } else if (self.navigationController.view != nil) {
        view = self.navigationController.view;
    } else {
        view = self.view;
    }
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:view animated:NO];
    hud.labelText = title;
    return hud;
}

- (MBProgressHUD *)showHUD {
    return [self showHUDFromTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Loading", @"Loading")];
}

- (MBProgressHUD *)showHUDFromTitle:(NSString *)title completedImage:(BOOL)completedImage {
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [self showHUDFromTitle:title];
    if (completedImage) {
        UIImage *checkmarkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"37x-Checkmark"];
        UIImageView *checkmarkImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:checkmarkImage];
        hud.customView = checkmarkImageView;
        hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
    } else {
        hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeText;
    }
    return hud;
}

- (void)hideHUD {
    [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.tabBarController.view animated:NO];
    [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.navigationController.view animated:NO];
    [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:NO];
}
```

Example:

```
[self showHUD];
[self hideHUD];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way

```
 [[[self tabBarController] tabBar] setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

As stated in this link:  [How can I make the tabbar action hidden when the view is loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582468/how-can-i-make-the-tabbar-action-hidden-when-the-view-is-loading)

Works great with MBProgressHUD

Answer (score 0):

Even more elegant to show the HUD from `UITabBarController`, since user interaction will be entirely controlled by `MBProgressHUD` until `hideAnimated:` is called:

```
// Show HUD from Tab Bar, to disable the tab bar items:
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.tabBarController.view
                                          animated:YES];

// Do some time-consuming stuff:
...

// Hide HUD and enable tab bar items:
[hud hideAnimated:YES];
```